# SQL Check Constraint - How to check for specific format?

Tags: sql, oracle, varchar, check-constraints

I am trying to add a CHECK constraint to my column for a football game score. The format has to be like such --> 4-2 (with the hyphen) Also both numbers cannot exceed 999.

Below is what I have so far which obviously does not work..Any ideas?
Column data type is `VARCHAR(7)`

```
Constraint ScoreCheck CHECK(Score LIKE '0-999'-'0-999');
```

Comment: Please tag your question with the database you are using.  Also, you should really be storing the score as two separate numeric columns, not as a single string column.  Very silly to store numbers as strings, and to store two numbers in a single field.

Comment: why do you put the values in on column instead of 2?

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Comment: Oracle. I agree that having 2 numbers in a field is silly, but this is the requirement  was given - A column that records the scores of both teams in the match

Comment: That's not a system requirement, it's a method of implementation. You can always make two separate columns look like a single entity in an application.

Answer (score 2):

The correct way to do this is to use a view or virtual column.  Virtual columns are available since 11g.  Simply define the virtual column in the table, such as:

```
create table  . . . 
    WinningScore int,
    LosingScore int,
    GameScore as (WinningScore || '-' || LosingScore)
)
```

(You can also use `alter table` for an existing table.)

[Here](https://oracle-base.com/articles/11g/virtual-columns-11gr1) is a bit of a primer on virtual columns.

Comment: Why is this the *correct way*? I agree that is in many respects optimal and/or desirable (and I'd probably go this route), but correct, I am not so sure.

Comment: @RenéNyffenegger . . . Because there are two separate attributes, the scores for each of the teams.  Each attribute should be stored in its own column.  Putting them together with a hyphen is an output format, and should not drive the data model.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of LIKE you should use REGEXP_LIKE

> Constraint ScoreCheck CHECK(
>   REGEXP_LIKE(Score,'^[0-9]{1,3}-[0-9]{1,3}$');

Also for further use, you should split this field into home team score and away team score and store them as integer so processing them would be easy